# android @Override error before function

Tags: android

I am having this error:

```
@Override
public void paint(Canvas canvas) {
}
```

The method `paint(Canvas)` of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method.
The error disappears only if I remove the `@Override` before the method.
I have already set in project properties java compiler on level 1.6

Can you help me?

Comment: What does the class MainActivity extend? Other than that - the error is self explaining itself, you are overriding a method which is not in the superclass

Comment: I don't believe `paint()` is a method in Activity... so you can't override a method that the super class doesn't have.

Comment: Are you sure it is not onDraw() method instead of paint()?

Comment: @rahul I thought that too. But Activity doesn't have `onDraw()`, View does...

Comment: It seems that he is trying to override the `onDraw` in a `View`. But we kinda need more details. Maybe he has a paint method in some other class but I really doubt that. Can you provide us more info on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are extending an `Activity` you can't override the paint method.

Paint is not an `Activity` method. You can only override existent methods from the class you are extending.

Also I never used Paint. Did you want to override the `onDraw(Canvas)` from the `View`?

Comment: Yes..now I don't understand superclass but onDraw works thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to override a method that doesn't "exist" in `MainActivity`'s superclass.

Some possible reasons (and solutions):

1. You forgot to add `extends ...` to the class you think it (`MainActivity`) inherits from.
2. You confused the method name, and it shouldn't be `paint()` - if this is the case - just change the method name
3. It is a new method for this class - and the annotation @Override should be deleted.
4. You changed the arguments for the original method - and you are overloading instead of overriding. You should stick with the same arguments if you really want to override it, or remove the `@Override` annotation if you are after overloading.

Answer (score 0):

if indeed the method that you want to override exists in the parent class then make sure you are compiling with at least java 1.6

So left click on your project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> Select at least java 1.6 then clean the project and rebuild.